# How do I update the manager for user?

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm using the following code

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient =
    new GraphServiceClient("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
        new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async(requestMessage) =>
        {
            requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
                new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", await GetTokenAsync(iclientApp));
        })
    );

User currentUser = await graphClient
    .Me
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();

string filter = String.Format("startswith(surname,'{0}')", "ADTest");
var users = await graphClient.Users
    .Request()
    .Filter(filter)
    .GetAsync();

var user = users[0];
DirectoryObject userManager = new DirectoryObject();
userManager.Id = currentUser.Id;

await graphClient
    .Users[user.Id]
    .Request()
    .UpdateAsync(new User()
    {
        Manager = userManager
    });
```

No error is throwing but the manager attribute is not getting updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few things going wrong here.

1. This action is a `PUT` so you should use `PutAsync()` rather than `UpdateAsync()` (which is a `POST`).
2. You're updating `user.Id` *and* assigning its manager as `user.Id`. In other words, you're telling Graph that this user's manager is the user themselves (which obviously is not the case).

Your code should look more like this:

```
// Create your client
GraphServiceClient graphClient =
    new GraphServiceClient("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
        new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async(requestMessage) =>
        {
            requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
                new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", await GetTokenAsync(iclientApp));
        })
    );

// Get your list of users
string filter = String.Format("startswith(surname,'{0}')", "ADTest");
var users = await graphClient.Users
    .Request()
    .Filter(filter)
    .GetAsync();

// Grab the first user returned to use as the manager
var manager = users[0];

// Assign this manager to the user currently signed in
await graphClient.Me.Manager.Reference.Request().PutAsync(manager.Id);
```

You can find an example of this in the SDK's [UsersTests unit test](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/f807196101e20d30fbc8628206a2eb5850334a92/tests/Microsoft.Graph.Test/Requests/Functional/UsersTests.cs#L249).