# Microsoft Graph update user profile using Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, microsoft-graph-api

I have been stuck on this for hours now.

I have the following code:

```
string[] scopes = new string[] { 
                    
                    "User.ReadWrite"
                };

                IPublicClientApplication publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(OAuthSettings.ApplicationId)
                .Build();

                InteractiveAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new InteractiveAuthenticationProvider(publicClientApplication, scopes);


                GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

                var user = new User
                {
                    Country = "ZA"
                };


                await graphClient.Me
                .Request()
                .UpdateAsync(user);
```

Yet every time I execute this I get the following error:

```
Code: generalException
Message: An error occurred sending the request
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In which line of code did you encounter this error?

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT In this line: ```await graphClient.Me.Request().UpdateAsync(user);```

Comment: I find one thread that you can take a look:[How do I update the manager for user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56129594/how-do-i-update-the-manager-for-user)

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT I will definitely give this a try when I'm back on that project again. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Updating user info is very limited unfortunately. Updating the country with delegated auth isn't possible. It should be doable with app-only auth and the `User.ReadWrite.All` permission. This is (admittedly) not well explained.

From the information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference?context=graph/api/1.0#remarks-30):

> User.ReadWrite and User.Readwrite.All delegated permissions allow the app to update the following profile properties for work or school accounts:
>
> - aboutMe
> - birthday
> - hireDate
> - interests
> - mobilePhone
> - mySite
> - pastProjects
> - photo
> - preferredName
> - responsibilities
> - schools
> - skills

There are some other gotchas as well (such as if the user is an admin, etc.).

Comment: I see, thanks for this. Can you tell me if there are issues in the code though? Because I just tried to update the mobilePhone and got the same error